# Is there any way to access WordPress database in core php code

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, mariadb

What I am trying to achieve: Store data into PHP database and WordPress database

for example, there are two databases, A is for corephp site and B is for wp site. Now when a user registers through corephp site, the entry is made in database A fine, along with that how should I make the same user entry into database B as well which is for WP, and not connected to corephp site anyhow right now.

Reason to connect both sites is, my WP site shows the woocommerce subscription purchases and I need to have that user data in WP database to see which user is registered with which membership subscription.

updated code:

```
$dir = getcwd().'/explore';
include $dir.'/wp-config.php';
include $dir.'/wp-load.php';
if ($f == 'register') {
    $register = Wo_RegisterUser($re_data, $in_code);
    if ($register === true) {
        wp_create_user($_POST['username'], $_POST['password'], $_POST['email']);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can achieve. you have need to include 'wp-config.php' and 'wp-load.php' in your core php project.  After that you have a need to call WordPress function 'wp_create_user' to insert new user data in the WordPress database.

for More details.
https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_create_user/

```
//include 'wp-config.php' and 'wp-load.php' in your core php project. Make sure you are passing the correct url of these two files.
include '/wp-config.php';
include '/wp-load.php';

$user_id = username_exists( $user_name );

if ( ! $user_id && false == email_exists( $user_email ) ) {
    $random_password = wp_generate_password( $length = 12, $include_standard_special_chars = false );
    $user_id = wp_create_user( $user_name, $random_password, $user_email );
} else {
    $random_password = __( 'User already exists.  Password inherited.', 'textdomain' );
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I am working on your given code. I do get the wordpress path successfully. However, in Inspect element - network I do get this error Status Code: 500 Internal Server Error when I add your given line
$user_id = username_exists( $user_name );

Comment: Are you creating user using ajax? what error you are getting?

Comment: It will work. This is the actual process. I tried the same thing working for me

Comment: yes I am using ajax on user registration page. right now i am using woowonder script in my php site. user registers fine in the php database as that code is written first.  
Then I am adding the below code, which shows 500 Internal server error in network.
$register = Wo_RegisterUser($re_data, $in_code);
        
if ($register === true) {

            $user_id = username_exists($_POST['username']);

}

Comment: where you added that file? add in file where  you are sending ajax request. you are getting the error because username_exists function not found. Just check wp-config.php and wp-load file included in your ajax file properly or not.

Comment: tried in both the files, where ajax is written and in file where the php function is. Sharing the partial array I get here:
current working directory/home/xpurity/public_html
scan directory
`Array ( [14] => wp-config.php [19] => wp-load.php)`

Comment: Are you sure these two file included properly? Just echo test in config file check for testing purpose. After ajax request test should be display if you included properly :)

Comment: Tried to echo in config file, it works fine but still stuck at 500 internal server error while writing `$user_id = username_exists($_POST['username'];`

Comment: use like - $username = $_POST['username'];   $user_id = username_exists($username ); Add your updated code in question I will see

Comment: I added your entire code given above and also tried just the below line 
 `wp_create_user($_POST['username'], $_POST['password'], $_POST['email']);` but still it shows internal server error and doesn't register a new user into php database.

Comment: Got error while including files. trying to debug code

Comment: When i echo in wp-config.php, it shows me the output but when i remove the echo it shows me internal server error.